# How to align rows of images of different heights?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, handlebars.js

I'm using bootstrap for my css.
I have a handlebars loop, where I place many images side by side:

```
<div class="row">
    {{#each imageData}}
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 center">
        <img src="{{url}}">
        <p>{{title}}</p>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Unfortunately, some of the images are of different dimensions. I set the following css:

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 400px;
}

But now some a rows have the expected number of images, others will have a fewer number (depending on the number of images that are the same height etc).

What CSS should I apply so that the expected number of images are on each row ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the height for the div and apply max-height for the images:

```
.row > div{
  width: 200px;/*example only*/
  height: 300px;/*example only*/
}
.row > div img{
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand - I'm using bootstrap so the layout will be responsive. If I set define a height for the div, won't it interfere with bootstrap ?

Comment: So, you may set height only for that div and using max-height will produce same row images... try it once!

Comment: Yes - it is much better now. But I still don't understand the concept fully. How do I know what values to set for width an height ? You used 200px, 300px. How do I decide ?

Comment: You may also use height in percentage, but care of parent div has height in fixed pixels.